# Applying a rule

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement, constraints

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.LOGINID)) AS LOGINID,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0140.EMAIL)) AS EMAIL,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.USERKEY)) AS ROLE
  FROM HOST0149 LEFT JOIN 
       HOST0140 ON HOST0149.PERSONKEY = HOST0140.PERSONKEY
```

Hi, I am trying to apply a rule on the select for email column. Sometimes the login ID will be the users email address, how do I apply a rule that if the email appears in the Login ID, to return nothing for the email column? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE...WHEN` should do. Basically, you handle both cases explicitely.

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.LOGINID)) AS LOGINID,
   CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0140.EMAIL)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.LOGINID)) THEN NULL ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0140.EMAIL)) END AS EMAIL,
   LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.USERKEY)) AS ROLE
FROM HOST0149 LEFT JOIN 
   HOST0140 ON HOST0149.PERSONKEY = HOST0140.PERSONKEY
```

Comment: Thanks for this Alex! This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I think a `case` expression does what you want:

```
SELECT LOGINID,
       (CASE WHEN LOGINID <> EMAIL THEN EMAIL END) as EMAIL,
       ROLE
FROM (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.LOGINID)) AS LOGINID,
             LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0140.EMAIL)) AS EMAIL,
             LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.USERKEY)) AS ROLE
      FROM HOST0149 LEFT JOIN 
           HOST0140
           ON HOST0149.PERSONKEY = HOST0140.PERSONKEY
     ) hh
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get result:

```
select LOGINID, EMAIL, ROLE FROM(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.LOGINID)) AS LOGINID,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0140.EMAIL)) AS EMAIL,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(HOST0149.USERKEY)) AS ROLE
  FROM HOST0149 LEFT JOIN 
       HOST0140 ON HOST0149.PERSONKEY = HOST0140.PERSONKEY)
WHERE EMAIL NOT LIKE  '%@%'
```